# Outlook 2016/2019 constant send/receive errors on google accounts

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-workspace

We use GSuite for our work's emails, and everybody in the office uses a mixture of Outlook 2016/2019 on their laptops for work email accounts, and sometimes non-work email accounts.

But constantly we run into issues where Outlook will get stuck receiving emails and just sits there syncing indefinitely. During this time no new emails arrive in the user's inbox (a.k.a. stuck), even though they will arrive on all their other devices (phones/tablets/etc.).

This can usually be resolved by;

1. stopping all send/receive tasks
2. close Outlook
3. open Task Manager and end any Outlook tasks still running (sometimes there's outlook zombies)
4. open Outlook

This solution above resolves it, but for some, this can be a weekly occurrence and is really wearing everybody's patience, and honestly isn't good enough.

This issue...

1. **only** seems to happen to non-exchange (eg. GSuite/Google) mail accounts
2. **only** on Outlook (mobile apps, other mail clients, etc. all function perfectly)
3. happens randomly across different machines
4. applies to all GSync, Outlook's IMAP and Outlook's OAuth setups

This leads me to believe that its an Outlook issue, and **not** a Google Server issue.

Has anyone experienced syncing issues with Google mail accounts in Outlook 2016/2019, and if so, know of any way to resolve this ongoing problem perminently?

*...and "NO", "simply" switching our large infrastructure setup over to Exchange is not an option.  That's like replacing your house, because one appliance has issues using the standard power socket!*

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, if our mailbox is too large, maybe we could set custom the send/receive group to "use the custom behavior defined" instead of the default setting--"download complete items", which may help us synchronize mailboxes more fast.
[image]

Also, if it only occurred on imap account, maybe you could try to set the "Mail to keep offline" to a short time to avoid the interference from large data files.

Comment: Thanks @Jade, like the refreshing suggestion, will give that a go and see (pray) if that works.

Comment: You're welcome, does it have any update?